# What's the proper way to ask for database review?

Tags: discussion, site-policy, asking-questions

I'm currently designing a database that I wanted to get some input on. It's entirely theoretical at this point, I haven't written a single line of SQL. Would it be acceptable to just post the database diagrams that I've made, pointing out the specific areas that I'm unsure about? If not, what other information should I include?

Regarding the diagrams, is there a prefered way of posting them, or is just uploading a screenshot acceptable?

Comment: FFS...emphatically ***not*** a duplicate. One asks "is this on-topic" and this asks "what's required for this on-topic question to be of sufficient quality?"

Comment: I don't think that that would be appropriate for CR. But you could try [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com), they're doing database design, too. I'm not sure if they do review, though.

Comment: Well, whatever you [did](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31237), it worked!

Comment: @Bobby according to [this question](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/149/28725) database reviews are on-topic.

Comment: @200 I did get an answer, and I didn't get any down votes...but I didn't get any up votes either. I'm wondering what the difference between a "good" question and a "great" question is in this context.

Comment: Well, then scratch my comment.

Answer (score 1):

someone has already mentioned that you check out [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com), which is a good idea.

another place that you might want to try, (please only post on one site in the stack network) would be [Programmers.stackexchange](http://programmers.stackexchange.com)

on their about page it says

[image: Algorithm and data structure concepts]

which from what you are saying is exactly what you are asking for help with.

I could be totally wrong and you could post there and get a bunch of downvotes, but it seems like a good place to post to me.